# downloaded file corrupted by getting response using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to download zip file by response using Node.js and express. I could downloaded it but it coruppted. I made 2 servers, one is for data storing and the other is front-end. I can't put the zip file on front-end server so I need to get it by response. following is the code:

for frontend (front-end-server)

```
    const express = require("express");
    
    const app     = express();
    const http    = require('http');
    const server  = http.createServer(app);
    
    const request = require('request');
    
    app.get("/api/download", (req, res) => {
    
            request('http://192.168.10.888:8088/getfile', (error, response, body) =>
            {
                        res.set({
                          'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
                            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="sample.zip"'
                            });
                        res.send(body);
            });
    
    });
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello app'));
    app.listen(8081, () => console.log('Listening on port 8081'));
```

for data storing (data-server)

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    const express = require("express");
    const app     = express();
    
    app.get('/getfile', function (req, res)
    {
        res.sendFile("/data/sample.zip");
    });
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello'));
    app.listen(8088, () => console.log('Listening on port 8088'));
```

data-server just return the file as stream and front-end-server get it by http-request and return it to browser so I expected download the zip file by simply type following URL

http://192.168.10.97:8081/api/download